# Scroll view doesn't work with constraint layout

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

Scroll view doesn't work with constraint layout all the content wrap up in my phone screen. Should i use scrollview as a parent layout ?What should be the width of my ScrollView Layout, i am confused with wrap_content and match_parent..............................................................................
   [This is what i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF5Lu.png)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1a1a22"
    tools:context="com.example.mrfrag.fullchargealarm.Settings">

   <ScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/scrollView6" android:fillViewport="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
      android:scrollbars = "vertical"
      android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">
     <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="FIRE1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="FFIRE" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textVie2321"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="FFIRE" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textVie23"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="FFIRE" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textVie45"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="FFIRE" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tesadasdxtVie3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="FFIRE" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/teasasdxtVie3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="FFIRE" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texasastVie3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="FFIRE" />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textVsase3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="FFIRE" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textasdasdVsase3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="FFIRE" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tasdasdextVsase3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="FFIRE" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texastVsase3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="FFIRE" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texVsase3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="FFIRE" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tetVsase3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="FFIRE" />

         </LinearLayout>
       </ScrollView>
     </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Try using NestedScrollView. I'm not sure it works but worth a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it to work, make the ScrollView the parent view, with width and height of `match_parent` (so it fills the screen). Then put the next layout inside it with a width of `match_parent` (so it's the width of the parent) and a height of `wrap_content` (so it can be taller than the parent height and scrolls to show the content).

What does `wrap_content` do? It lets the view be as tall as needed to display its content. If it's taller than the parent then the `ScrollView` lets you scroll up and down to see the content.

For example:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- this could be a constraint layout instead if you want -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- STUFF -->

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In your case the parent ConstraintLayout isn't necessary since there's only one subview and it's filling the parent view, but if you wanted to keep the heirarchy you have, just change the `LinearLayout` immediately inside the `ScrollView` to a height of `wrap_content`